# At mongoDb uninstall on Windows 10 I got this error: Missing "mongodb-windows-x86_64-4.4.1-signed.msi" file

Tags: windows, mongodb

At mongoDb uninstall got error missing the file: mongodb-windows-x86_64-4.4.1-signed.msi.

I guess it has to be in the Windows/Installer folder but it's not there. On mongodb website, I found 4.4.3 version installer file, 4.2 or older. I tried with Google and I didn't found it anywhere. How could I uninstall it without this file or fix the error message? I tried to reinstall but it doesn't work either because it have to first uninstall and I got the same error.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you encountered other error messages when installing mongoDb ?

Comment: No.I havent.I guess the problem is some 3rd party cleaner app(like CCleaner ) deleted the installer package.And i cant find exactly the same 4.4.1 installer package on internet.

Comment: Try install the package with Chocolatey  after you uninstall the third-party app that is effecting your installation for version 4.4.1. See the folowing link: https://chocolatey.org/packages/mongodb.install

Comment: Install current version 4.4.3 - afterwards you can remove with the same installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it manually, it's no big deal

- Delete files from program folder
- Delete folders for data (`dbPath`) and log files
- Delete the services, for example

  ```
  sc stop <service name> (or net stop <service name>)
  sc config <service name> start=disabled
  sc delete <service name>
  ```